What is range of $P$ values and range of $Q$ values for any given semiprime $N$?
Given $PQ = N$ where $P<Q$ and both $P$ and $Q$ are odd. I determined that the range of values for $P$ is: $\frac{\sqrt{N}}{2} < P \le \sqrt{N}$ and the range of values for $Q$ is: $\sqrt{N} < Q \le 2\sqrt{N}$. Could some verify that this is correct or close please?
Also notice that the size of the range for $P$ is half the size of the range of $Q$. Does this mean that there are twice as many possible values for $Q$ as there are for $P$?
$\textbf{CORRECTION}$
My initial attempt fails if $\frac{Q}{P} > 4$
The best I can do to find the range of $P$ and $Q$ is by holding an arbitrary $Q$ constant while examining the distance $d_1 = \sqrt{N}-P$ as $P$ approaches $Q$. If we take the partial derivative of $d_1$ with respect to $P$, we get:
$$d_1 = \sqrt{P}\sqrt{Q} - P$$
$$\frac{\partial d_1}{\partial P} = \frac{\sqrt{Q}}{2\sqrt{P}} - 1$$
Setting:
$$\frac{\partial d_1}{\partial P} = 0$$
We get the relationship:
$$P_{max} = \frac{Q}{4}$$
Substituting this back into $d_1$ says that the maximum distance of $d_{1} = P_{max}$.
So the range of $P$ is:
$$(\sqrt{N} - P_{max}) < P \le \sqrt{N}$$
and since I held $Q$ constant, we are forced to use the range of $Q$ as:
$$\sqrt{N} \le Q < N$$
$\textbf{Question}$
Is there a much better way to express the range of $P$ and $Q$ as a function of $N, P, Q$... or is my second attempt the best we can do? I'm looking for a way to evaluate $N$ and then say... that $P > P_0$ and that $Q < Q_0$. That is to say, is there some lower and upper limits solely based on evaluating $N$? I doubt there is.
$\textbf{I'm trying to avoid this:}$
$$1<P<\sqrt{N}$$
and:
$$\sqrt{N}<Q<N$$

$P$ could be less than $\dfrac{\sqrt N}2$; consider $P=2, Q=11$.  Also, $P\color{red}<\sqrt N$, for if $P=\sqrt N$ and $Q>P$ we would have $PQ>N$.

You changed the question so now $P$ and $Q$ are odd, so now I'll say consider $P=3, Q=13$

@J.W.Tanner it appears that if $\frac{Q}{P} > 4$ then my statement fails. I'd like to modify my question.

$P=3$ and $Q=13$ contradict your new claim as well. I would say $1\lt P\lt\sqrt N$ and $\sqrt N\lt Q\lt N$

@J.W.Tanner Now it's correct!

The best we could ever get is $3\le P\le\sqrt N$ and $\sqrt N\le Q\le N/3$. This is satisfied by infinitely many semiprimes, namely all those of the form $N=3Q$. Your lower bound is correct, but your upper bound is not: $Q<\sqrt N+Q/2$ is equivalent to $Q<2\sqrt N$ which is not always true.

@GregMartin I need to review what I did, I may have made a misstep.
